# How do I change Ionic 7s ion-input border color?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

With the release of Ionic 7 I am refactoring `ion-item` to use the new simplified syntax. I've gotten everything to work as it was before, besides the base color of the input. In the picture below, email field is using old syntax, password field using the new one. For some reason, `--border-color` (in SCSS) has no effect on `ion-input` unlike `ion-item` using the old syntax. Mind you, `--border-width` and `--border-radius` for example work without issue on `ion-input`.

[image]

Adding `!important` to the end of `--border-color` seems to work, but this overrides all other color states like successful and error, which means you won't know if your input is correct or not until you try to login and see the error messages.

Using normal `border` just adds another border around the ion-input element itself.

Adding `color="secondary"` to `ion-input` element itself seems to only affect the highlighted color which is why I've set to `danger` to mimic the specific behavior we've had before.

After reading the docs for about the 17th time, I still cannot find anything that mentions changing the base color of `ion-input`. Any ideas?

Password input using the new simplified syntax:

```
<ion-input fill="outline" class="box" labelPlacement="floating" type="password" formControlName="password"
    [ngClass]="{ 'input-error': submitted && form.password.errors }" color="danger">
    <div slot="label">{{ 'CONFIGURATION.PASSWORD.TITLE' |
        customTranslate }}<ion-note color="danger"> *</ion-note></div>
</ion-input>
```